# Creating an Alphabet tracing layout doesn't flow correctly

Tags: css

I'm creating an alphabet tracing/writing worksheet layout. It doesn't overflow correctly.

I tried duplicating the code sample with fewer letters so it doesn't overflow. The problem is some letters are longer than others so they would continue to overflow.

I expect the excess letters to move down and recreate the top/middle/bottom border.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px
}

.top {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  height: 30px
}

.center {
  border-top: 1px dashed #000;
  height: 30px
}

.letter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  font-size: 84px;
  padding-bottom: 30px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top">
  </div>
  <div class="center">
  </div>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="letter">A B C D E O P Q R S T U V W X Y Zs</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

- Edited to add snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the `font-family` since each one is unique in height and width. You'll get varying lengths for each letter if the `font-family` is serif or sans-serif type, but if it is a monospace type then all lengths for each letter is uniformly the same.

The following demo uses `text-decoration: overline underline` and an overlay with `text-decoration: line-through dashed`. There's two examples:

1. **font-family: Arial** (san-serif)
2. **font-family: Consolas** (monospace)

```css
:root {
  font: 500 9vw/1.2 Arial;
}

.alphabet {
  position: relative;
  height: 7rem;
  max-width: 96%;
  margin: 5vh 2vw;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1rem;
  font-stretch: ultra-expanded
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
}

.edges {
  z-index: 0;
  top: .3rem;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: overline underline rgba(255, 255, 128, 0.7);
}

.edges del {
  color: transparent;
}

.middle {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
  color: transparent;
  text-decoration: line-through dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

h4 {
  margin: 0 0 -3vw 0
}

.consolas {
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.consolas h4 {
  margin: 0 0 -2vh 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem
}

.consolas .text {
  height: 0.5rem;
}

.consolas .edges {
  top: 0.2rem
}
```

```html
<figure class='alphabet'>
  <h4>Arial</h4>
  <figcaption class='text'>
    <mark class='line edges'>Aa&emsp14;Bb&emsp14;Cc&emsp14;Dd&emsp14;Ee&emsp14;Ff&emsp14;Gg&emsp14;Hh&emsp14;Ii&emsp14;Jj&emsp14;Kk&emsp14;Ll&emsp14;Mm&emsp14;Nn&emsp14;Oo&emsp14;Pp&emsp14;Qq&emsp14;Rr&emsp14;Ss&emsp14;Tt&emsp14;Uu&emsp14;Vv&emsp14;Ww&emsp14;Xx&emsp14;Yy&emsp14;Zz<del>XXXx</del></mark>
    <mark class='line middle'>Aa&emsp14;Bb&emsp14;Cc&emsp14;Dd&emsp14;Ee&emsp14;Ff&emsp14;Gg&emsp14;Hh&emsp14;Ii&emsp14;Jj&emsp14;Kk&emsp14;Ll&emsp14;Mm&emsp14;Nn&emsp14;Oo&emsp14;Pp&emsp14;Qq&emsp14;Rr&emsp14;Ss&emsp14;Tt&emsp14;Uu&emsp14;Vv&emsp14;Ww&emsp14;Xx&emsp14;Yy&emsp14;ZzXXXx</mark>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class='alphabet consolas'>
  <h4>Consolas</h4>
  <figcaption class='text'>
    <mark class='line edges'>Aa&emsp14;Bb&emsp14;Cc&emsp14;Dd&emsp14;Ee&emsp14;Ff&emsp14;Gg&emsp14;Hh&emsp14;Ii&emsp14;Jj&emsp14;Kk&emsp14;Ll&emsp14;Mm&emsp14;Nn&emsp14;Oo&emsp14;Pp&emsp14;Qq&emsp14;Rr&emsp14;Ss&emsp14;Tt&emsp14;Uu&emsp14;Vv&emsp14;Ww&emsp14;Xx&emsp14;Yy&emsp14;Zz<del>XXXx</del></mark>
    <mark class='line middle'>Aa&emsp14;Bb&emsp14;Cc&emsp14;Dd&emsp14;Ee&emsp14;Ff&emsp14;Gg&emsp14;Hh&emsp14;Ii&emsp14;Jj&emsp14;Kk&emsp14;Ll&emsp14;Mm&emsp14;Nn&emsp14;Oo&emsp14;Pp&emsp14;Qq&emsp14;Rr&emsp14;Ss&emsp14;Tt&emsp14;Uu&emsp14;Vv&emsp14;Ww&emsp14;Xx&emsp14;Yy&emsp14;ZzXXXx</mark>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```